When presenting a ViewController as a sheet, how can I present the presentingViewController from scaling
When presenting ViewControllers as sheets using sheetPresentationController if the detent is .full or larger than the window height, the presentingViewController gets pushed back, dimmed, and scales down.
Is there any way to modify or disable this behavior?


The only solution I've found so far is a total hack:
Instead of using a full detent, use context.maximumDetentIdentifier to ensure the detent is never actually full:
sheet.detents = [.custom(resolver: { context in
    0.999 * context.maximumDetentValue
})]


